# Remove rows from xlsx file with Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a xlsx file containing many columns but for the example I'll describe it with only two columns :

```
period | value
--------------
1402   | AB
1402   | ABxx
1403   | AC
1403   | ACxx
1404   | MM
1404   | MMXX
```

I need to cut the rows where `period < 1403 or period > 1403`.

So this is how I want to do it :

1. Open the above xlsx file
2. Loop through all the columns & Rows
3. Copy rows where  `period < 1403 or period > 1403` to a new xlsxfile
4. close both xlsx files

I'm using xlsxwriter and this is how I manage to create the first xlsx file from a dictionnary.

```
def saveDataToNewFile(filename,sheetName, data) :
    # Create workbook
    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.add_worksheet(sheetName)
    # Write header
    headers = data[0].keys()
    for column, header in enumerate(headers):
        ws.write(0, column, header)
    date_format = wb.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
    # Write data
    for row, row_data in enumerate(data, start=1):
        for column, key in enumerate(headers):
            ws.write(row, column, row_data[key],date_format)
    wb.close()
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

The code for writing to a new xlsx file looks correct. So all you need to do is get the data you need to write from the original file.

I'd suggest reading in the data using [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and skipping any data that doesn't match your criteria.